# Can't find kaggle.json file in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I'm trying to download the kaggle imagenet object localization challenge data into google colab so that I can use it to train my model. Kaggle uses an API for easy and fast access to their datasets. (https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api) However, when calling the command "kaggle competitions download -c imagenet-object-localization-challenge" in google colab, it can't find the kaggle.json file which contains my username and api-key.

I haven't had this problem on my mac when running a jupyter notebook, but since I want to use google's gpu for my model, I started using google colab. Because the kaggle API expects the username and api-key to be in a kaggle.json file located in a .kaggle directory, I first created the directory .kaggle and then the file kaggle.json, into which I wrote my username and api-key (The example below doesn't display my username and api-key). I then tried to configure the path to my json file for kaggle to use when calling the kaggle download command.

```py
!pip install kaggle

!mkdir .kaggle
!touch .kaggle/kaggle.json

api_token = {"username":"username","key":"api-key"}

import json
import zipfile
import os
with open('/content/.kaggle/kaggle.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(api_token, file)

!chmod 600 /content/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!kaggle config path -p /content
```

However, when running the last command, I got the error:

```
IOError: Could not find kaggle.json. Make sure it's located in /root/.kaggle. Or use the environment method.
```

My goal was to use the following commands to get the dataset from kaggle:

```
!kaggle competitions download -c imagenet-object-localization-challenge
os.chdir('/content/competitions/imagenet-object-localization-challenge')
for file in os.listdir():
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall()
    zip_ref.close()
```

I don't understand why the kaggle API can't find my json file. How can I use the API in google colab?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error said, you need to put kaggle.json in the right place.

Try:

```
!mv .kaggle /root/
```

Then run your code again.

Answer (score 44):

According to [kaggle api documentation](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api) the location where credentials json is looking for is `~/.kaggle/kaggle.json` as google colab environment is Linux based.
In your snippet you try to config `path` parameter, but it is not used to looking for credential json:

> - path: Folder where file(s) will be downloaded, defaults to current working directory

So the full working snippet for google colab environment would be:

```
!mkdir ~/.kaggle
!touch ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json

api_token = {"username":"username","key":"api-key"}

import json

with open('/root/.kaggle/kaggle.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(api_token, file)

!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

And then some api call like

```
!kaggle datasets download -d datamunge/sign-language-mnist
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer and should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Good answer. Please don't write code as `root` though.

Comment: The last step `chmod` is recommended by Kaggle and a warning message would pop up on Kaggle if the file permission isn't set to 600 to prevent other users on the system to see the API token.

Answer (score 18):

You can find the JSON file that you need to place form Kaggle's portal itself. Just log into kaggle, go to [your account page](https://www.kaggle.com/me/account) and then click 'Create New API Token' and it will give you a JSON file that needs to be placed.

[image]

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you!
After I clicked on 'Create New API Token', a save to location popup window appeared and I saved it under ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json and now the kaggle download command works.

Answer (score 5):

My own method, and if you like to minimise '!' addition to  Egor B Eremeev answer above.

This may be beneficial depending on your use case and in the long run lead to cleaner code if you are scripting.

```py
import json 
import os
from pathlib import Path

# your api key
api_key = {
'username':"username" ,
'key':"some_api_key"}

# uses pathlib Path
kaggle_path = Path('/root/.kaggle')
os.makedirs(kaggle_path, exist_ok=True)

# opens file and dumps python dict to json object 
with open (kaggle_path/'kaggle.json', 'w') as handl:
    json.dump(api_key,handl)

os.chmod(kaggle_path/'kaggle.json', 600)
```

Comment: Nice. This is the only answer that worked for me. Good job.

Answer (score 3):

Run this code in cell to config the environment

```
import os
os.environ["KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR"] = "/path_to_your_kaggle.json_file"
```

They've written their GitHub repo that you can config the environment of kaggle.json error appears in colab or windows too:

> You can define a shell environment variable `KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR` to change this location to `$KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR/kaggle.json` (on Windows it will be `%KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR%\kaggle.json`).

--
[Refer this](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api#api-credentials)

[image: environment config image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you are a windows user, move your kaggle.json into .kaggle folder, that you are able to find it in your system root (which is in your username folder).

Answer (score 0):

This link is helpful for uploading kaggle dataset into collab:
https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/general/74235

You can download kaggle.json file from https://www.kaggle.com/settings, look into API

& for dataset download command- go on respective dataset which you want to download click on 3 dots(look into attached image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq4M3.jpg)