# Where to locate kaggle.json file oni Windows 10 for use by google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, dtreeviz

[Can't find kaggle.json file in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816537/cant-find-kaggle-json-file-in-google-colab)
[very much related]

I am running Windows 10 box to run Google Colab.

My first cell runs fine

```
!pip install -Uqq fastbook
!pip install --user graphviz 
!pip install kaggle 
!pip install dtreeviz
```

as does

`from fastbook import *`

but this throws an error

```
from kaggle import API
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kaggle/api/kaggle_api_extended.py in authenticate(self)
164                 raise IOError('Could not find {}. Make sure it\'s located in'
165                               ' {}. Or use the environment method.'.format(
--> 166 self.config_file, self.config_dir)) 167 168 # Step 3: load into configuration!

OSError: Could not find kaggle.json. Make sure it's located in /root/.kaggle. Or use the environment method.
```

Some commentators have said to put kabble.json in

```
c:\Users\rph.kaggle ## rph being my user account on the box
```

others have said to put the file in

```
%HOMEDIR%.kaggle
```

Well, I have done both.

Putting the file in [c:\Users\rph.kaggle] meant that the file was in [%HOMEDIR%.kaggle]

But the same error still gets thrown.

What next?